# How to Do Growing Table / List

Tags: sapui5

### JS

```
var model = new JSONModel();
model.setData(data);
this.getView().byId("Table").setModel(model);
var table = this.getView().byId("Table");
table.bindItems({
    path: "/",
    template: new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
        cells: [
            new sap.m.Image({
                src: "{photo}"
            }),
            new sap.m.Text({
                text: "{name}"
            })
        ]
    })
});
```

Here I have few data. Using above code I can list in table. Now I want to list only first 10 items in table and rest of the data will show after scroll down only. After scroll down mouse I need to call a function to get next 10 datas. How we can call a function after scroll down in sapUi5;

Comment: I see you edited your question. There is no need to call a function extra to get the next batch of data. UI5 does it automatically for you according to the [`growingThreshold`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.ListBase/methods/setGrowingThreshold) value. In our case, UI5 sends a request for the [next 10 items when the user scrolls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47633857/5846045).

Comment: I did server side pagination. So first time I have only 10 data. For next 10 data, I have to call same api with limit and offset.

Comment: I just updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47633857/5846045) below. Feel free to leave a comment if something is not clear.

Comment: Also, since you're not working with OData but serverside JSON with parameters, you might want to show your interest in this enhancement request: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/882.

Answer (score 6):

## OData

In order to enable growing on scroll, you need to take the following into account:

- The [`sap.m.ListBase`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.ListBase) control (e.g. `sap.m.Table`) needs:

  - `growing="true"`
  - `growingThreshold="<number of entries to load>"`
  - `growingScrollToLoad="true"`
- The list control needs to be inside a [scrollable container](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/66029f6f5a554a4eb700676bec1460dc).

  > (`growingScrollToLoad`) can only be used if the `growing` property is set to `true` and only if there is one instance of `sap.m.List` or `sap.m.Table` inside the scrollable scroll container (e.g `sap.m.Page`). [(Source)](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.ListBase#methods/setGrowingScrollToLoad)

Run this example to see it in action:

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/model/odata/v4/ODataModel",
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
], async function (ODataModel, XMLView) {
  "use strict";

  const model = new ODataModel({
    serviceUrl: "https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/(S(5pfdhufu5ymr2jh0az0vcwqe))/",
    autoExpandSelect: true,
  });

  const control = await XMLView.create({
    definition: `<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
      xmlns="sap.m"
      displayBlock="true"
      height="100%"
    >
      <App>
        <Page showHeader="false">
          <List
            growing="true"
            growingThreshold="5"
            growingScrollToLoad="true"
            items="{/People}"
          >
            <StandardListItem title="{FirstName}" />
          </List>
        </Page>
      </App>
    </mvc:View>`,
    models: model,
  });
  control.placeAt("content");
});
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://sdk.openui5.org/nightly/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-oninit="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m,sap.ui.unified,sap.ui.layout"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_horizon_dark"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitForTheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody"></body>
```

---

## Manual Hook

> How we can call a function after scroll down in SAPUI5?

In case there is no OData service (no `$top` & `$skip`) but the app still needs to be notified when the user reached almost the end of the list (either by scrolling or by keyboard), you can make use of the [`sap.ui.core.delegate.ScrollEnablement`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.delegate.ScrollEnablement). And since the list control is supposed to be already inside a [scrollable container](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/66029f6f5a554a4eb700676bec1460dc) (such as [Page](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.Page)), creating a new instance of `ScrollEnablement` is not necessary. Instead, there is a handy API to retrieve the corresponding `ScrollEnablement` delegate which is [`getScrollDelegate`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/55fa2321c893cc41237a8acfe6694091964587de/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/library.js#L3199-L3220). Once you have the delegate object, call [`setGrowingList`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.delegate.ScrollEnablement#methods/setGrowingList) which awaits a hook function that gets invoked when the bottom is almost reached.

Example:

```js
sap.ui.require([
  "sap/m/library",
], sapMLib => sapMLib.getScrollDelegate(myListControl).setGrowingList(() => {
  // Your code to load more data
}, sapMLib.ListGrowingDirection.Downwards));
```

### Note

- The API `getScrollDelegate` returns only the reference when the scrollable parent control has already [created an instance of ScrollEnablement](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.52/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/Page.js#L239-L249) before rendering.
- The API `setGrowingList` is *protected*, meaning it's not meant to be used by application developers. Please use the API only when extending the target control.

Comment: For the manual scenario, how do you signal to the control that there are more items than currently loaded (and that growing is a possibility)? When binding to an OData source, if the list is not long enough to go over the screen, there is normally a button to indicate that more data can be loaded (because it knows from the $count that there are more items than shown). But in the manual scenario, surely you must be able to indicate that this is the case somehow?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am binding to a JSON model that I am filling.

Comment: @mydoghasworms Good question. I'm afraid the only option is to see in the OpenUI5 source code how OData handles the scenario and implement similarly, bases on what your non-OData service supports (`$count` equivalent)

Comment: I have since found a blog post on sap.com that provides a solution which works does what I need: https://blogs.sap.com/2020/12/07/implement-pagination-using-sap.m.table-and-jsonmodel/ This extens the JSON model with the ability to return a total count other than just the records actually in the model, i.e. set by your application.

Comment: @mydoghasworms Might work technically for now, but keep in mind that [UI5 doesn't actually support extending existing model implementations (`JSONModel`, `ODataModel`)](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/91f1c7ef6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070) ... _> "The subclassing of standard models is not supported in OpenUI5."_ ... Extending `JSONModel` might break the application in the future.

Comment: Thanks for that info Boghyon, that is interesting. And yet, the person who authored that blog post is an SAP employee. Oh well, so far that has provided the cleanest and most elegant solution to my problem. In the event that something breaks in future, I guess we will just have to make the necessary changes. (Fortunately, the extensions are very small!)

Comment: @mydoghasworms Now I added the same comment in the blog post. Just as a reminder for future readers. I did see here and there blog posts written by SAP employees not following "best practices" or even violating compatibility rules. Either way, technical blog posts, in general, should be double-checked with the documentation. But sometimes documentation content can be also wrong or outdated. In that case, an issue at https://github.com/SAP/openui5-docs (or https://github.com/SAP-docs/sapui5) can be created.

Comment: There is of course a difference between "not supported" and "won't work" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set property [growing](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListBase/methods/setGrowing) to true. And also set property [growingThreshold](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListBase/methods/setGrowingThreshold) to 10.

Comment: After scroll down mouse I need to call a function to get next 10 data.